# Jasmine toBeUndefined

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine and assumed using the `.not.toBeDefined()` or `.toBeUndefined()` matches you could check if a variable is `undefined`:

```
describe('toBeDefined', function() {

    it('should be defined', function() {
        var obj = {};
        expect(obj).toBeDefined(); // Passes
    });

    it('should not be defined using .not.tobeDefined()', function() {
        //var obj = {};
        expect(obj).not.toBeDefined(); // Fails // ReferenceError: obj is not defined
    });

    it('should not be defined using .tobeUnefined()', function() {
        //var obj = {};
        expect(obj).toBeUndefined(); // Fails // ReferenceError: obj is not defined
    });

});
```

I completely get that this would fail within the code, but I assumed using those matches, it wouldn't. Am I just using these wrong, or is it not possible to write a spec to check if something is `undefined`?

Comment: This error is determined by the ecmasceipt engine which by nature throws since you are accessing a non-defined variable.  This is totally expected as it is not Jasmine's fault.  It's the way the language behaves.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is that

```
  expect(obj).toBeUndefined();
```

fails *before the call to Jasmine even happens*.  It's erroneous to refer to a variable that's not defined (in new browsers or in "strict" mode at least).

Try this setup instead:

```
it('should not be defined using .tobeUnefined()', function() {
    var obj = {};
    expect(obj.not_defined).toBeUndefined(); 
});
```

In that code, there's a variable "obj" whose value is an empty object. It's OK in JavaScript to refer to a non-existent property of an object, and because such a reference results in `undefined` the test will pass.  Another way to do it would be:

```
it('should not be defined using .tobeUnefined()', function() {
  var no_value;

  expect(no_value).toBeUndefined();
});
```

Comment: Right. Thanks for the insight. :)

Comment: You could also do: `expect(typeof obj).toBe('undefined')`

Comment: Thanks, now I can get this working: describe("A girl", function() {
    it("has no name.",function(){
        expect({}.arya).toBeUndefined();
    })
});

Answer (score 4):

Note that your error says that `obj is not defined`.

It does not say that obj is *undefined*.

*undefined* is actually a data type in Javascript.

Any declared variable without an assignment is given a value of *undefined* by default, but that variable must be declared.

So when Jasmine tests whether a value is *undefined*, it is determining if `obj === undefined`.

If you declare

```
var obj;
```

then `obj` will test as undefined.

If you do not declare `obj`, then there is nothing for the Jasmine matcher to compare against the data type of *undefined*.